# how can i make the infinity disappear when i divide by 0?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone help me make the infinity alert disappear when I divide by 0?
This is my code:

```js
if (operatie === "+") {
  resultat = num1 + num2;
  alert(resultat);
} else if (operatie === "-") {
  resultat = num1 - num2;
  alert(resultat);
} else if (operatie === "/") {
  resultat = num1 / num2;
  alert(resultat);

} else if (operatie === "*") {
  resultat = num1 * num2;
  alert(resultat);
} else {
  alert("Operatia nu este una corecta. Alegeti +, -, *, /");
}
```

Comment: Never divide by zero. Catch it before you do the division. if (num2 != 0) {/*do division*/}

Comment: `else if (operatie === "/") { if (num2 === 0) { alert("Don't divide by zero!"); } else{ /* rest of division code you had earlier */ }`

Comment: From your recollection of maths in school, what does dividing by 0 mean?

Comment: well this is how the assignment should be made, that if i divide any number by zero an alert to appear and say"operatie incorecta" instead of infinity

Answer (score 0):

Slightly changed a line.
This is a shortcut to check if the divisor is equal to zero.

```js
if (operatie === "+") {
  resultat = num1 + num2;
  alert(resultat);
} else if (operatie === "-") {
  resultat = num1 - num2;
  alert(resultat);
} else if (operatie === "/") {
  resultat = (num2 == 0) ? "---" : (num1 / num2);

  alert(resultat);

} else if (operatie === "*") {
  resultat = num1 * num2;
  alert(resultat);
} else {
  alert("Operatia nu este una corecta. Alegeti +, -, *, /");
}
```

Comment: Please comment your answer

Comment: hi, i need that instead of the alert "infinity to appear when i insert for instance 8/0 , an alert to appear that says "operatie imposibila", i may be doing something wrong cause this doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

That is also possible.

```js
 

   if (operatie === "+") {
      resultat = num1 + num2;
      alert(resultat);
    } else if (operatie === "-") {
      resultat = num1 - num2;
      alert(resultat);
    } else if (operatie === "/") {
if( num2 == 0   ) {
     alert("operatie imposibila") 
} else{
     resultat =  num1 / num2 ;
     alert(resultat);
}
     

     

    } else if (operatie === "*") {
      resultat = num1 * num2;
      alert(resultat);
    } else {
      alert("Operatia nu este una corecta. Alegeti +, -, *, /");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Sending out error messages is not the best way of dealing with unwanted situations. Usually it is best to avoid them altogether:

```js
document.querySelectorAll("div.btns").forEach(d=>d.innerHTML="+-*/".replace(/./g,"<button>$&</button>").replace(">/"," disabled>/"));
document.addEventListener("input",ev=>{let el=ev.target;
 if (el.classList.contains("denom"))
  el.nextElementSibling.children[3].disabled=!-el.value
})
document.onclick=ev=>{let el=ev.target,p=el.parentNode;
 if(el.tagName==="BUTTON"){
  p.nextElementSibling.value=
  ops[[...p.children].indexOf(el)](+p.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling.value,+p.previousElementSibling.value)
}}
const ops=[(a,b)=>a+b,(a,b)=>a-b,
           (a,b)=>a*b,(a,b)=>a/b];
```

```html
<input type="text" placeholder="enter num1"><input type="text" placeholder="enter num2" class="denom">
<div class="btns"></div>
<input type="text" placeholder="result ...">
```

In my snippet the "divide" action is disabled for as long as the denominator (second input field) has a value that is equivalent to `0` (after type conversion).